# Backbone.js tutorials and learning resources

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Are there any other backbone.js tutorials or learning resources for beginners than [Introduction](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) or [Hello backbone.js](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/)?

Comment: I would suggest going through underscore.js, then attempting backbone.js -- It will be a less bumpier ride.

Comment: You can take a look on very back series here http://www.codebeerstartups.com/category/backbone-js/

Comment: Hackr has a good compilation of some of the best Backbone.js tutorials - http://hackr.io/tutorials/backbone-js

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I forgot the [Backbone tutorials!](http://backbonetutorials.com/)

Read the [annotated sample application](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html)

There is also this [tutorial by Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-spas-jquerys-best-friends/)

The [dailyJS has something to say too](http://dailyjs.com/2011/04/04/node-tutorial-19/).

And [Quora has a *lot* of information](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-resources-for-Backbone-js)

And a [very basic series for learning backbone js](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/category/backbone-js/)

Answer (score 6):

Brief introduction to backbone.js
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-started-with-backbone-js/

Answer (score 3):

I also found this interisting tutorial for testing Backbone.js

http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/03/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon.html

Answer (score 3):

I will added this one : [Aaron](http://aaronhardy.com/javascript/javascript-architecture-the-basics/) it's really helped me out!!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a decent tutorial. It goes over a simple (hello world kind of simple) example. It also has links to documentation and demo apps.

http://www.plexical.com/blog/2010/11/18/backbone-js-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is already marked as answered, but just to add to the knowledge here for anyone coming across this question:

I found this walk-through of implementing Backbone.js useful:

http://andyet.net/blog/2010/oct/29/building-a-single-page-app-with-backbonejs-undersc/

Answer (score 2):

I know 2 Backbone.js resource collections you might be interested in:

- [Derick Bailey's Backbone Resources](http://backbonetraining.net/resources)
- [Backbone.js Wiki Link Collection](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Tutorials%2C-blog-posts-and-example-sites)

Answer (score 1):

Peepcode has two paid screencasts on backbone

- https://peepcode.com/products/backbone-js
- https://peepcode.com/products/backbone-ii

Comment: The third episode, covering Networking and Persistence, just came out.